# same displacement want it to appear similar on two objects

Tags: modeling, displacement

[image]I am trying to apply a displacement texture onto an object.However the same displacement is only appearing correct on the sphere (1) object and not the box (2).What am I doing wrong?[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that you need proper UV map. Upload your blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: thanks just uploaded[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2038" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2038/)

Comment: I will need this screenshot (47).jpg file as well ;)

Comment: done posted on question